# Open source music player for windows

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, music

I'm looking for a music player (not video player) for windows which is:

- open-source
- simple to use
- easy to organise albums
- support .mp3, .flac sound formats

It should not have a lot of features or be too fancy (a light-weight player)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Clementine](https://www.clementine-player.org/)

[image: Clementine]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

**Features**

> - Search and play your local music library.
> - Listen to internet radio from Spotify, Grooveshark, SomaFM, Magnatune, Jamendo, SKY.fm, Digitally Imported, JAZZRADIO.com, Soundcloud, Icecast and Subsonic servers.
> - Search and play songs you've uploaded to Box, Dropbox, Google Drive, and OneDrive
> - Create smart playlists and dynamic playlists.
> - Tabbed playlists, import and export M3U, XSPF, PLS and ASX.
> - CUE sheet support.
> - Play audio CDs.
> - Visualisations from projectM.
> - Lyrics and artist biographies and photos.
> - Transcode music into MP3, Ogg Vorbis, Ogg Speex, FLAC or AAC.
> - Edit tags on MP3 and OGG files, organise your music.
> - Fetch missing tags from MusicBrainz.
> - Discover and download Podcasts.
> - Download missing album cover art from Last.fm and Amazon.
> - Cross-platform - works on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.
> - Native desktop notifications on Linux (libnotify) and Mac OS X (Growl).
> - Remote control using an Android device, a Wii Remote, MPRIS or the command-line.
> - Copy music to your iPod, iPhone, MTP or mass-storage USB player.
> - Queue manager

Comment: I'll give this a try.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.en_GB.html) for both music and video on many platforms:

- Free, libre & FOSS
- Supports just about every media file I have come across MPEG-2, DivX, H.264, MKV, WebM, WMV, MP3.
- Cross platform (even mobile)
- Plays everything: files, discs, webcams, devices and streams
- No ads/spyware/tracking
- Can do media conversion and streaming

Comment: It is not very good for organising music albums. :|

Comment: @Abbey You asked what people use - this is what __I__ use.  I use play lists to group the tracks into the order that I use!

Answer (score 2):

I used **[Miro](http://www.getmiro.com/)** for a while when I was a Windows user.

It supports most, if not all, file types for music and video.

It does a good job (in my opinion) organizing artists and albums.

[Miro](http://www.getmiro.com/) is open source, lightweight, and easy to use. It's available for Linux, MacOS, and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

maybe also [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) is interesting for you, here only some features:

- support for FLAC, Opus, mp3 and many others
- tagging and album list management
- clear, lightweight and customizable user interface
- a big amount of [add-ons](http://www.foobar2000.org/components) to extend the functions
- but it is not completely open source! - the core is closed source and the SDK with with a lot of components is under BSD-license

Answer (score 0):

if you like the old "mediaplayer-style" have a look at [Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.org/):
it fits all your points and much more, similar to [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/)...

---

if you like the "winamp-style" try [AIMP](http://www.aimp.ru/):

- supports your recommended formats and much more
- supports multiple play lists, tag editor and manages your audio library
- its a real lightweight audio-player
- and also has a lot of [addons](http://www.aimp.ru/index.php?do=catalog) to add features and skins
- on the downside it is completely closed source! - but i've listed it here because it is a relly good piece of software.